# Cannot write logs

Tags: azure, centos6, rethinkdb

I created a new Centos 6.5 VM in Azure and had RethinkDB running within a few minutes, which is great! However, I've been in the "Data Explorer" web interface and playing with ReQL queries for a while and suddenly I got an issue: "Cannot write logs" "File cannot be written on server xxx" "Log file is inaccessible on server xxx". I'm relatively new to Linux and hoping someone has previously resolved this.

To my surprise, the only reference to this error on the web is an issue on the RethinkDB repo: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2488 which doesn't really provide a solution, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi Smymian, are you starting rethinkdb manually or through the init script with an instance configuration in /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d?

Can you check two things:
`$ df -h`
this should give you the amount of free disk space, just to check that the disk isn't full.
`$ sudo chmod -R uog+rw /var/rethinkdb/*`
this adds write permissions to the RethinkDB data files for every user on the system (this is a bit unsafe, but worth a test since you're probably not sharing the VM with other users?). Afterwards you should restart RethinkDB to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I started RethinkDB from a remote SSH session on my Macbook and typed disown before exiting the SSH session so that RethinkDB continues to run on the remote server. There are multi GB of free space, so I don't think that's the issue. Running $ sudo chmod -R uog+rw /var/rethinkdb/* produced the error "No Such file or directory"

Comment: I can see a rethinkdb folder in /etc/rethinkdb Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh I meant /var/lib/rethinkdb. neumino got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo chmod -R uog+rw /var/lib/rethinkdb/*
```

If it doesn't work, try to just start rethinkdb from the command line to see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you! I had to start a new instance via a config file in /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d but all good now.